# How to install docker to configure selenoid on windows?

Tags: python, windows, docker, selenoid

I have created an app, that use selenoid, to use it you need docker and wsl

I am interested in the easiet way to download docker, that can be done automaticly, using code, so users won`t need to install it by themselves

And it is not docker desktop, because it contains docker engine, compose and others, but selenoid dont need all of them

I am using windows, but hopefully it will be possible to download on mac and linus too

So PLEASE, is there any easy ways to solve my problem?

I will be grateful for any help
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't hesitate to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve question quality and get a better change to have your uqestion answered

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to install docker.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sudo bash -s
```